# is it possible to selectively inject proxies of the same auto-proxied spring class?

Tags: spring

I have a security and transaction annotated spring bean, the spring auto-proxies this class both for txn and security and autowires that everywhere. Is it  possible to selectively inject the proxies of this class into another bean, i.e there cud be 4 scenarios : 1. autowire unproxied 2. autowire with security proxy 3. autowire with txn proxy 4. autowire with both

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to wire bean into proxy manually using [different name](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-proxy-creator-example/) (see [ProxyFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/ProxyFactoryBean.html))